# C++ XUL Frameworks

Tags: c++

What are the most popular XUL Frameworks for C++.  I am interested in both X Platform and also Platform Dependant ones.

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't make sense at the moment (June 2010). There's only one XUL framework, by Mozilla.